# Angular2 и ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Приветствую! 
Хочу прояснить такой вопрос. Для удобного роутинга в AngularJs (первая версия) у нас имеется ui-router, очень удобная версия роутинга на основе состояний. Изучая Angular2 я рассчитывал там увидеть нечто подобное из коробки, но увы...
Хотелось бы задать вопрос, это сознательно сделано и там уже есть некие механизмы, которые лучше или просто решили сделать все как в первом и потом снова ждать кто со стороны сделает луче, чем есть?
Если нужно использовать роутинг из коробки, то поястните в чем их разница и преимущество по сравнению с ui-router плиз!
Месяц назад я начал писать большое приложение на Angular1, попутно читал про второй, вот теперь вдобавок задаюсь вопросом, стоит ли продолжать писать на первом, или лучше сразу начать писать на втором, к моменту готовности, надеюсь и Angular2 зарелизится и будет полно всяких приблуд и примочек.
Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется теперь речь идет от навигации по состояниям в навигацию по компонентам, в том числе можно делать многоуровневые структуры.

По поводу миграции, посмотрите:
http://slides.com/christhielen/ui-router-ng1-to-ng2#/

Comment: Как бы да, но в rc5 снова модули добавили, теперь и ui-router-ng2 снова переделывать приходится.[issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2914) Да и все равно мы же в зависимости от состояния должны компонентами управлять...